# Windows CE application disappears after device restart

Tags: windows-ce

I have wrote an application for Datalogic Falcon X3 terminals. The devices runs Windows CE 6 Proffesional.

Application is deployed on devices, and everything works fine, except one thing - every time, when the battery in device depletes, the application files disappears.

I suppose, that this is some sort of factory reset.

Notably, not everything is wiped - i.e. WiFi setting remains unchanged.

Is there a way, to keep my application on device, when the battery power is off?

Comment: HI Jakub, sorry for reviving such an old post, but did you ever find a way to run your application in an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying your application file to RAM (i.e. folder other than SD card / NAND flash or any ROM based directory), then the application won't persisted after power off or restart.

But the registry settings such as WiFi settings are persisted, because, these are saved to [ROM based hive registry](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/08/11/windows-ce-what-is-hive-registry.aspx) in your OS.

So, If you want to have your application for next boot-up, you must save the application file to any ROM based directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the device data sheet. Probably Falcon X3 have RAM-based file system. In this case you need to copy your application to ROM-based directory (see the manuals, again, to find the name of ROM-directory).